# How to give a dynamically rendered element it's own data value & target it in it's parent component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a **BaseMenuItem** component that has normal button elements as well as special **news** elements.
I have added a ticker effect to the **news** type els and want to stop the ticker on that element when it's clicked. Currently the click event stops the ticker effect on the whole group.

How can I target a single element from that group?

There are two methods, `openNews` one showing the specific news article that the element is linked to.
And `clearItemType` that clears the `itemType` upon recieving the emitted event from the **BaseMenuItem** component.

I'm just not sure which element to target to change it's `itemType`.
Does Vuejs have a way to make an unique data value for dynamically generated elements?

If you need anymore information please let me know!

Cheers!

BaseMenuItem

```
<template>
 <q-btn align="left" dense flat class="main-menu-item" v-on="$listeners">
    <div class="flex no-wrap items-center full-width">
      <iconz v-if="iconz" :name="iconz" type="pop" color="black" class="mr-md" />
      <q-icon v-if="menuIcon" :name="menuIcon" class="text-black mr-md" />
      <div @click="$emit('stop-ticker')" v-if="itemType === 'news'" class="ellipsis _ticker">
        <div class="ellipsis _ticker-item">{{ title }}</div>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <div class="ellipsis">{{ title }}</div>
      </div>
      <slot>
        <div class="ml-auto"></div>
        <div class="_subtitle mr-md" v-if="subtitle">{{ subtitle }}</div>
        <q-icon name="keyboard_arrow_right" class="_right-side" />
        <ComingSoon v-if="comingSoonShow" />
      </slot>
    </div>
  </q-btn>
</template>


<style lang="sass" scoped>
// $
.main-menu-item
  display: block
  font-size: 15px
  position: relative
  width: 100%
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F5F5F5
  +py(10px)
  ._left-side
    color: #000000
  ._subtitle
    margin-left: auto
    opacity: 0.7

._ticker
  position: absolute
  font-weight: bold
  margin-left: 2em
  width: 82%
  &-item
    display: inline-block
    padding-left: 100%
    animation: ticker 8s linear infinite

@keyframes ticker
  to
    transform: translateX(-100%)
</style>

<script>
import { iconz } from 'vue-iconz'

export default {
  name: 'MainMenuItem',
  components: { iconz },
  props: {
    comingSoonShow: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    title: { type: String, default: 'menu' },
    subtitle: { type: String, default: '' },
    menuIcon: { type: String, default: '' },
    iconz: { type: String, default: '' },
    itemType: { type: String, default: '' },
  }
}
</script>
```

MainMenuPage

```
<template>
  <div class="eachMenuGroup" v-if="newsList.length">
          <MainMenuItem
            v-for="news in newsList"
            :key="news.id"
            @click="openNews(news)"
            :title="news.title"
            :itemType="itemType"
            :class="{ readLink: readNewsList[news.id] }"
            menuIcon="contactless"
            @stop-ticker="clearItemType"
          ></MainMenuItem>
   </div>
</template>
<style lang="sass" scoped>
.readLink
  font-weight: 500
</style>

<script>
 methods: {
    openNews(postInfo) {
      dbAuthUser().merge({ seenNewsPosts: { [postInfo.id]: true } })
      Browser.open({ url: postInfo.url, presentationStyle: 'popover' })
    },
    clearItemType() {
      this.itemType = ''
      return
    },
</script>
```

Comment: To be sure I understand correctly : you want your `stop-ticker` event > `clearItemType` function to target the appropriate DOM el that fired the event ? What do you want to change within `clearItemType` ?

Comment: Yes! The clearItemType is there to set the type back to '', so that it loses the ticker ability. Maybe I am going about this all wrong, but the `itemType` prop in BaseMenuItem is all I could think of to make this all happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I edited since your latest comment. See below

To target the exact element within your `v-for` that fired the event, you can use `$refs` by using an index :

```
<MainMenuItem v-for="(item, index) in items" :ref="`menuItem--${index}`" @stop-ticker="clearItemType(index)" />
```

In your method:

```
clearItemType(index){
   console.log(this.$refs[`menuItem--${index}`])
// this is the DOM el that fired the event

}
```

Edited version after your comments:

If you pass the exact same prop to each el of your `v-for` you wont be able to modify its value just for one child in the parent context.

Instead, keep an array of distinctive values in your parent. Each child will receive one specific prop that you can change accordingly in the parent either by listening to an child emitted event or by passing index as click event as I've done below for simplicity.

See snippet below

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const Item = {
  name: 'Item',
  props: ['name', 'isActive'],
  template: `<div>I am clicked {{ isActive }}!</div>`,
};

const App = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  components: {
    Item
  },
  data: {
    items: ["item1", "item2"],
    activeItemTypes: []
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(index) {
      this.activeItemTypes = this.activeItemTypes.includes(index) ? this.activeItemTypes.filter(i => i !== index) : [...this.activeItemTypes, index]
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <Item v-for="(item, i) in items" :name="item"  @click.native="toggle(i)" :isActive="activeItemTypes.includes(i)"/>
    </div>
  `,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
This log me back [vueComponent] and though it doesn't have it's own index inside of the vueComponent, it does tell me the <itemType> and that it is being set to ''.
This is great. 
I guess now the final step would be to add a watcher event for a change in itemType?
Because presently, though it does clear the itemType, the ticker keeps scrolling. 
Am I wrong about the use of a watcher? Or is there a better way to handle this sort of thing?

Cheers again for all the help and coming back today!

Comment: Since I am currently binding itemType to itemType, I get the mutating prop val error when I try and do `itemComponent[0].itemType = ''`. But I haveitemType as a data value as well. Should I rename that data value for this to work? Because even though I get the error, the ticker DOES stop. I'm very close all thank to your help, Pierre!

Comment: I edited my first answer.Let me know if we are getting closer so I can update / rephrase

Comment: Boy, I hate to keep you working on this with me, but I've never seen this type of syntax before. The `const Item` is the child component correct? In which it's prop values are in an Array? (I dont think I've ever seen that)

I tried to work in this code with mine and ended up with another prop in my child component `clearedItems: { type: Boolean },` and then another data value in the Parent `clearedItemGroup` which is an empty array. 
I've logged my new `clearItemType(index)` in a method and show the indexs get pushed into the `clearedItemGroup` eg; [0,1,2]
But this isn't any different

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help so far and I apologize for my lacking ability to understand this. I don't want to waste any more of you time, so don't feel obligated to continue trying to help me here. What you've done so far is more than I could ask for

Comment: "const Item is the child component correct?"  correct.  "In which it's prop values are in an Array?" nope... its props value is a boolean answering the question "is my index in the parent's activeIndex array ?".  Then, The click event (or alternatively child emitted event) adds or remove the item's own index from the parent, so your boolean prop stays in sync with the parent state. That should be enough for the child to perform its own logic: all it has to know is wether it is "active"  or not.

Comment: The confusion comes from this syntax `props: ['name', 'isActive']`. In my child component the two props are 
`itemType: { type: String, default: '' }` and
 `clearedItems: { type: Boolean }` (clearedItems is acting as the isActive)
However, once I get to the parent component, I get totally lost in your snippet. 
Inside the parent's data there is the **items** array with ["item1", "item2"].
In my code I have each element being pushed into that **activeItemTypes: []** (my name is different). But is that not enough? Once they're that array, what are you supposed to do?

Comment: What I wound up doing was just having a prop `ticker: {type: Boolean, default: false}` and putting data in my child component  `tickerScroll: falsee` a method `stopTicker(){ this.tickerScroll = false}` to change it and a `mounted(){ this.tickerScroll = this.ticker === true}` hook. 

Then on the parent I can just have `ticker="true"` for the news items and get rid of all that itemType nonsense all together. Not sure how much I like the implimenation, but it gets the job done I suppose. 

I still need to save that to localdata or some sort of state, so it keeps it's type on page refresh tho